# Subspaces -vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a nonempty subset of R^n. Show that V is a subspace of R^n if and only if for all u,v ∈ V and c∈R,u+cv∈ V.  Any1 can help with this ques?I don't really know how to show this.appreciate ur help!

Comment: What is the definition of vector space? A subspace is a subset which is also a vector space...

Answer (score 1):

To show a set $S$ is a subspace, you must show $0\in S$, it is closed under scalar multiplication, and closed under vector addition.

You are basically given all that.